# Statistical analysis (comparison) of high-frequency timeseries data for two temperature loggers?

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, paired-data, method-comparison

I am working with high-frequency (144 measurements/day) temperature data. It was two individual temp instruments measuring at equal intervals (10 mins) at the same stationary location for 120 days.
One sensor was calibrated, while the other was not. The uncalibrated instrument shows high drift after about a month of use.

I am looking to determine the statistical significance between between the logger types (calibrated vs. uncalibrated).
I was wondering if there was a way to compare the **mean daily values of each instrument (calibrated vs. uncalibrated)** and then determine at ******approximately what day*** did the daily means become statistical different*** (i.e. day 24 of 120).
To start, I was thinking of using a paired t-test. However, the data (>10,000 points for each dataset) are non-parametric. I have tried looping the t.test to run per day, but this is not accurately representative of the variation between the instruments over time.

My data looks something like this:

| Date | Instrument | daily mean | daily_sd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-02 | 1 | 105.3425 | 0.569485 |
| 2022-05-02 | 2 | 108.0292 | 0.657267 |
| 2022-05-03 | 1 | 104.416 | 0.79805 |
| 2022-05-23 | 2 | 106.639 | 0.865599 |
| 2022-05-04 | 1 | 103.389 | 0.83729 |
| 2022-05-04 | 2 | 68.124 | 1.37303 |

However, I can use raw data (144 measurements/day) instead of a daily mean if necessary for a proper analysis.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated!